# multiple image input training using dataset object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How to use a dataset object as input in the `model.fit()` training loop, for a model with multiple inputs?
Trying to pass the dataset itself gives me the following error:

```
Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.MapDataset'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>
```

My case here:

I have a multiple input model built with keras
The inputs are named `'First'`, `'Second'` and `'Third'`

I have an image dataset in keras-style:

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......a_image_1.jpg
......a_image_2.jpg
...class_b/
......b_image_1.jpg
......b_image_2.jpg
```

I create the dataset object using `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`:

```
train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(train_dir,
                                             shuffle=False,
                                             label_mode='categorical',
                                             batch_size=hyperparameters["BATCH_SIZE"],
                                             image_size=IMG_SIZE)
```

Now, each image is divided in 3 parts, each part serving as input to each of the inputs of the model. I take care of that using some map functions. This is not relevant tot he problem and I will not include it. I cannot use the cropping layers included in TF because of unrelated reasons.

I then try to start the training loop:

```
 history = model.fit([train_dataset1, 
                      train_dataset2, 
                      train_dataset3,
                      ],
                      epochs=epochs, 
                      callbacks=callbacks,
                      validation_data=validation_dataset
                      validation_steps=steps
                      )
```

And here is where I get the error.
I have tried some other approaches, like using a dict instead of a list.
The problem seems to be that when training a model with multiple inputs, the fit() loop expects data to come as a list for x-values and a list for y-values, but I haven't been able to split the dataset object into the required formats

I have read many topics on this, but all use datasets that are created using the `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` method, which is not applicable in my case

Additionally, there is no indication of how the validation dataset has to be structured (at least according to the [model.fit() documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit))

I have found some guidance saying that the validation dataset must have the same number of input/outputs as the training datasets (makes sense), but again, no indication on how to build or feed the validation dataset for a multiple input model

Comment: How are your labels distributed among your datasets?

Comment: Using tf.data.Dataset.zip method will solve your problem as far as I understand: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip

Comment: There are 2 labels, in each dataset. I will give the zip() method a look, will report

Comment: I created the "zipped" dataset, but when called by model.fit() it seems to return only a single element of the first dataset, instead of a tuple with the first element of each nested dataset

Comment: It's confusing, it seems it should work. if I do (print("element:", element) for element in zip_ds.as_numpy_iterator()), the output show it does actually return 3 individual items per call to the generator, but when I use zipped_ds as the training data, it will treat the first element it returns (image, label) as the single input for the model. I have no idea of what's going on

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code to replicate the error and fix the issue.

Comment: I think I narrowed it down and stumbled upon a Keras bug. I created 3 separate Dataset objects, then used the tf.data.Dataset.zip() method to create a single dataset. Each call to the Dataset returns a tuple of 3 elements, each being a tuple of a single element from each zipped dataset.  Problem is that the Keras training loop has trouble handling the input in this way. You can follow the issue here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16016

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in a comment above, I managed to solve this issue, but there seems to be a bug [in the way the Keras fit() training loops handles the input from a zipped dataset](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16016), so if you need to do this, you'll have to wait until it's fixed or [write your own training loop](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/).

### How to approach this

I ended up solving this issue in the following way:

I created 3 separate dataset objects. Then to feed it to the model.fit() training loop, I used the tf.data.Dataset.zip() (as Almog David pointed out in the comments) method to create a single dataset containing the 3 separate datasets:

```
train_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(train_dir,
                                             shuffle=False,
                                             label_mode='categorical',
                                             batch_size=32,
                                             image_size=IMG_SIZE)
validation_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(validation_dir,
                                             shuffle=False,
                                             label_mode='categorical',
                                             batch_size=32,
                                             image_size=IMG_SIZE)

def resize_data1(images, classes):
    return (tfimgcrop(images,
                        offset_height=0,
                        offset_width=0,
                        target_height=64,
                        target_width=64),
                    classes)
def resize_data2(images, classes):
    return (tfimgcrop(images,
                        offset_height=0,
                        offset_width=64,
                        target_height=64,
                        target_width=64),
                    classes)
def resize_data3(images, classes):
    return (tfimgcrop(images,
                        offset_height=0,
                    offset_width=128,
                    target_height=64,
                    target_width=64),
                classes)

train_dataset_unb = train_dataset.unbatch()
train_dataset1 = train_dataset_unb.map(resize_data1)
train_dataset2 = train_dataset_unb.map(resize_data2)
train_dataset3 = train_dataset_unb.map(resize_data3)
train_dataset_zip = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_dataset1, train_dataset2, train_dataset3))

validation_dataset_unb = validation_dataset.unbatch()
validation_dataset1 = validation_dataset_unb.map(resize_data1)
validation_dataset2 = validation_dataset_unb.map(resize_data2)
validation_dataset3 = validation_dataset_unb.map(resize_data3)
validation_dataset_zip = tf.data.Dataset.zip((validation_dataset1, validation_dataset2, validation_dataset3))
```

### Validating the approach by testing what the zipped datasets return in each call:

#### Printing elements in a for() loop using the `tf.data.Dataset.as_numpy_iterator()` method:

```
for element in train_dataset_zip.as_numpy_iterator():
print("element", element)
```

Outputs:

```
element [[[x1, y1, z1], [c1,]], [[x2, y2, z2], [c2,]], [[x3, y3, z3], [c3,]]] 
element [[[x1, y1, z1], [c1,]], [[x2, y2, z2], [c2,]], [[x3, y3, z3], [c3,]]] 
[...]
element [[[x1, y1, z1], [c1,]], [[x2, y2, z2], [c2,]], [[x3, y3, z3], [c3,]]]
```

#### Printing elements in a for() loop using the python intrinsic enumerate() function:

```
for idx, (ds1, ds2, ds3) in enumerate(train_dataset_zip):
    print("ds1: ", ds1)
    print("ds2: ", ds2)
    print("ds3: ", ds3)
```

Outputs:

```
ds1:  (<tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 64, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=[(large array with raw pixel values)], , dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>
ds2:  (<tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 64, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=[(large array with raw pixel values)], , dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>
ds3:  (<tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 64, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=[(large array with raw pixel values)], , dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>
ds1:  (<tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 64, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=[(large array with raw pixel values)], , dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>
ds2:  (<tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 64, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=[(large array with raw pixel values)], , dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>
ds3:  (<tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 64, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=[(large array with raw pixel values)], , dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>
[...]
ds1:  (<tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 64, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=[(large array with raw pixel values)], , dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>
ds2:  (<tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 64, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=[(large array with raw pixel values)], , dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>
ds3:  (<tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 64, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=[(large array with raw pixel values)], , dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>
```